# Как реализовать циклический список round-robin и подсчитать количество обращений к элементу?

Tags: java, list, балансировка

Сценарий:

Для списка из 3 элементов:

```
[A, B, C]
```

Можно обращаться к нему сколько угодно раз.

Есть дополнительная функция, подсчитывающая количество обращений к каждому элементу.

Например, если вызвать 7 раз, то должно вернуть:

```
[A, B, C, A, B, C, A]
```

Счетчик обращений должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
+–––––––––––+–––––––––––––––+
|  Элемент  |   Обращений   |
+–––––––––––+–––––––––––––––+
|     A     |       3       |
+–––––––––––+–––––––––––––––+
|     B     |       2       |
+–––––––––––+–––––––––––––––+
|     C     |       2       |
+–––––––––––+–––––––––––––––+
```

Нужно предусмотреть ещё одну дополнительную функцию, которая позволяет указать список элементов, для фильтрации. Тот же пример, вызываем 7 раз, фильтруем `[C]`:

```
[A, B, A, B, A, B, A]
```

```
+–––––––––––+–––––––––––––––+
|  Элемент  |   Обращений   |
+–––––––––––+–––––––––––––––+
|     A     |       4       |
+–––––––––––+–––––––––––––––+
|     B     |       3       |
+–––––––––––+–––––––––––––––+
|     C     |       0       |
+–––––––––––+–––––––––––––––+
```

Последующие вызовы `getNextOne()` всегда должны получать элемент, с меньшим количеством обращений. Реализация симулирует сбалансированную нагрузку количества обращений. Таким образом, если следующая попытка вызвать 10 раз, то должно вернуть:

```
[C, C, C, B, C, A, B, C, A, B, C, A]
```

```
+–––––––––––+–––––––––––––––+
|  Элемент  |   Обращений   |
+–––––––––––+–––––––––––––––+
|     A     |       7       |
+–––––––––––+–––––––––––––––+
|     B     |       6       |
+–––––––––––+–––––––––––––––+
|     C     |       6       |
+–––––––––––+–––––––––––––––+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно реализовать *список циклического доступа* на основе одной карты `TreeMap`.

| TreeMap |  |
| --- | --- |
| Ключ | `Integer` количество обращений |
| Значение | `List<T>` лист объектов, к которым были обращения |

#### Класс `CircularList<T>`

| Методы | Этот код работает в Java 7 без дополнительных библиотек |
| --- | --- |
| ``` getOne() ``` | возвращает `T` первый элемент с наименьшим количеством обращений |
| ``` getOne(List<T> filter) ``` | возвращает `T` первый элемент с наименьшим количеством обращений, который не содержится в фильтре |
| ``` getOne(T filterIn) ``` | возвращает `T` фильтруемый элемент |
| ``` getCount(T element) ``` | возвращает `int` количество обращений к искомому элементу, или `-1` если элемент не найден |
| ``` status() ``` | возвращает `String` текущий статус карты |

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VndTttIFL7PU0y5SsAYUCtWWkhUCF2p2q16AeoN4sIlAzU4TtZ2WLEtEiSLuhV0eYSV9glSliwUmvQVxk/EnjNjO/4ZOwkU9kd1hAnDzPn5zs93Em9pO9pkrU7Nrcr29bVerdcsh2zBotpwdEMdn8vl6o2Xhr5O1g3NtskzTTfJ6xyBy1u3Hc0J/l3WrfWGoVk/6LYzv1LydvLdlr6jOZRs6KZmkBWL0mdaff6p6dBNainEO1Ai1KBVajo2KRKT/hRsLOULYIovbGp8PHhPxsnjumZpVWKADMJ67IN7ws5Z222yDrtyj1nXPWIf1dCBqb5Vwoew2XnfdhRXCHmAl75B8lxNEcxrGAZ584bvU239Z5ov4PJ0gVjUaVjmXOSk80q3Vd85td5w8tMK93DBsrRdrrPERRcK/YN76S4LHYR9Zh13n52ii8R9z67A50/w03WbxD0grMva7MJbOXZ/xfeEXQJIV@zCfQtnDwCmU/j7k0BuH3B7h7thZzZm9q65/sqqmeB4hayQTeo8NxGCKGBTUwSNAyUo98Jtusd9m1vubwQjBQsXYMjx7S2O6Ia8UZ@YjrUrSzNchxyLhaVmGN/plu3wY/lCNISeFLJN8SSXoILb39PETj@FdjSjQcN7X@BCfHcmRpK4gqPnAJVADaBpR6St@CUEerl@1aLV2g7NT0vUApqIK@gPC@wQ9y1Y05vEG6DMIW/DRnx3rKBxGI4e@8u3tsP@5Du9eDQhGj0Uita5@7CnlSgjYZtXNyUsm2SJANKKcEIGGTt3T7h67kSHnWFCIYIIme9Nj13ytPqAJt8yofywQtm@8CIbtRkijDaTCTKTNJgbc87OEJ8AMyUUgy4CfwBOvPONclvwrpmArq9fdKFC2KJ4T5Egd4Z@QkBPvfDxTnnJFV9I0g1y4z1mAm8pfVgjYn0DVK1SyXt4SDSjXkiNQDPPjyZkSGtAs/RQVQJFEuF32Qojyrze6xk4VLsWDLWhGw40kGhy/gLyMTM5DGgztILDmAMImXq3/T8sPem/wk/xLNjnurxshZ1n3ALRCg7cE54vIZ9Y5wY04leaAExGKl1MWW7NPk/epqD5iGphJPsMW3wMTrCg0MxEUXmxCRG7WJFRe8B2WQQxOZNBCnOpPRu1SwvHPeRg8wgGpIl9w@@xR5FTGzWL5AdT4LexYuOry9DHCnHU8RpMfXgNR3t4Zbktdz2a4@5ROhEGICC64KfgEYlTg/vHbbJfqg4T7oGXX@s104Gp2oa2WUgzL4oVlSAVJpoWkgyvcN7dg@Y9yhiRiKc/RoCVmdpTZwpsJNhyxKjAKzMxWcRMjwyHKXmeOVeIoo1muOcHpHKGIy8tqm3L/72XG7wSxiEOe1dg0WYfMXlYNyfzwg/2A5/hJQbt5W6qUrl5mwyy0DcssyN@ndO@zmn/2TntqSkdzhJWSwezkU8OORmtBMbd41QESAxf7/@SUWX4T@ujf2L/oqOJ6KdDzCfp3T2dS@JxVOmPDc2wg9LPGjjuYZSQ9Z//5TzxzxDhFyLFOyHIL0mW90CcI5LoDQn1duQaj9MwFJQqII08RxmF731CTSWndMpnv0NYeE@Jf@fSjrWctnsYahph7paMEH5f9872hp8cZKUuKXTYFxLOFbTC4mJs1FKwSyP0kzPDhyFzQNHBPUC6XGuYTp/J4oxyJ@TOP4nEKDr8QTqb3PzUHjATZOWyJyL8Hc/ghzXxNsTJCmOD/V6aWAnMlx1LNzf5Q7eGnXjaEq1ZW3VqYn9KJTx@vkMtS6/QFC394zfSE9KGpf@HSGfJs8Odml4hVQhdXohZXSOatWmHtUYeLIpd4gkdKeYk7Tm6v5Tn3GGrms2f8I0tjClkbBFvZbwtjYUfui3v2g6tqrWGo9ZBj2OY4rncHHrxerq4uqCQRYWUFbK01k8KnuZYETrQ1fQc/JonM/h7YiKOXlwBF696PSthKWTxBBkjY8lJe5GUyVL0nktmq8Sdwc6qfoKFvF5TyMPiKndbIY@Kq4sDvH84uvMYiTRvl/B1D/75zilktrg6MMKPRncy1cMF/irDz2LozmN7V37PCr@/AU9FUq/tDRQRtHyenFzO7AiHnviHJme8DrF3ff03)

```java
public class CircularList<T> {
    private final TreeMap<Integer, List<T>> elements = new TreeMap<>();

    /**
     * @param list обязательный.
     */
    public CircularList(List<T> list) {
        if (list == null || list.size() == 0) return;
        this.elements.put(0, new ArrayList<>(list));
    }

    /**
     * @return первый элемент с наименьшим количеством обращений.
     */
    public synchronized T getOne() {
        // вытащить первую запись с наименьшим количеством обращений
        Map.Entry<Integer, List<T>> entry = this.elements.pollFirstEntry();
        Integer key = entry.getKey();
        List<T> value = entry.getValue();
        // вытащить первый элемент из списка
        T element = value.remove(0);
        // если в списке что-то осталось, положить его обратно в карту
        if (value.size() > 0) this.elements.put(key, value);
        // взять следующий список с большим количеством обращений
        List<T> newValue = this.elements.get(key + 1);
        // создать его, если не существует
        if (newValue == null) newValue = new ArrayList<>();
        // добавить текущий элемент в этот список
        newValue.add(element);
        // обновить катру
        this.elements.put(key + 1, newValue);
        // первый элемент с наименьшим количеством обращений
        return element;
    }

    /**
     * @param filter список фильтруемых элементов.
     * @return первый элемент с наименьшим количеством
     * обращений, который не содержится в фильтре.
     */
    public synchronized T getOne(List<T> filter) {
        // некорректный фильтр не применяется
        if (filter == null || filter.size() == 0) return getOne();
        Integer key = -1;
        List<T> value;
        T element = null;
        // обходим записи карты
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<T>> entry : this.elements.entrySet()) {
            key = entry.getKey();
            value = entry.getValue();
            element = null;
            // обходим элементы списка
            for (T el : value) {
                // первый элемент, который не содержится в фильтре
                if (!filter.contains(el)) {
                    element = el;
                    // удалить этот элемент из списка
                    value.remove(el);
                    // если в списке ничего не осталось, удалить запись карты
                    if (value.size() == 0) this.elements.remove(key);
                    break;
                }
            }
            // если элемент не найден
            if (element != null) break;
        }
        // если элемент не найден, фильтр не применяется
        if (element == null) return getOne();
        // взять следующий список с большим количеством обращений
        List<T> newValue = this.elements.get(key + 1);
        // создать его, если не существует
        if (newValue == null) newValue = new ArrayList<>();
        // добавить текущий элемент в этот список
        newValue.add(element);
        // обновить катру
        this.elements.put(key + 1, newValue);
        // первый элемент с наименьшим количеством обращений
        return element;
    }

    /**
     * @param filterIn фильтруемый элемент.
     * @return фильтруемый элемент.
     */
    public synchronized T getOne(T filterIn) {
        // некорректный фильтр не применяется
        if (filterIn == null) return getOne();
        // обходим записи карты
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<T>> entry : this.elements.entrySet()) {
            Integer key = entry.getKey();
            List<T> value = entry.getValue();
            // обходим элементы списка
            for (T element : value) {
                // если элемент найден
                if (filterIn.equals(element)) {
                    // удалить этот элемент из списка
                    value.remove(element);
                    // если в списке ничего не осталось, удалить запись карты
                    if (value.size() == 0) this.elements.remove(key);
                    // взять следующий список с большим количеством обращений
                    List<T> newValue = this.elements.get(key + 1);
                    // создать его, если не существует
                    if (newValue == null) newValue = new ArrayList<>();
                    // добавить текущий элемент в этот список
                    newValue.add(element);
                    // обновить катру
                    this.elements.put(key + 1, newValue);
                    // фильтруемый элемент
                    return element;
                }
            }
        }
        // если элемент не найден, фильтр не применяется
        return getOne();
    }

    /**
     * Поиск элемента в списках карты.
     *
     * @param element искомый элемент.
     * @return количество обращений к искомому
     * элементу, или -1 если элемент не найден.
     */
    public int getCount(T element) {
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<T>> entry : this.elements.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().contains(element)) {
                return entry.getKey();
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    /**
     * @return текущий статус карты.
     */
    public String status() {
        return elements.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return elements.toString();
    }
}
```

```java
// Тест
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CircularList<String> list =
            new CircularList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D"));
    System.out.println(list); // {0=[A, B, C, D]}
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.print(list.getOne(Arrays.asList("A")) + " ");
        // B C D B C D B C D B
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(list.status()); // {0=[A], 3=[C, D], 4=[B]}
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        System.out.print(list.getOne("D") + " ");
        // D D D
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(list.status()); // {0=[A], 3=[C], 4=[B], 6=[D]}
    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        System.out.print(list.getOne() + " ");
        // A A A C A B C A B C A D B C
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(list.status()); // {6=[A], 7=[D, B, C]}
    System.out.println(list.getCount("A")); // 6
    System.out.println(list.getCount("E")); // -1
}
```

Comment: Почитайте про очереди с приоритетом, вы их по сути пытаетесь эмулировать.

Answer (score 0):

Задача решается с помощью целочисленного деления и остатка от него. При фильтрации проще создать новый список без удалённых элементов.

N элементов, Q запросов, получается список из LargerNum значений Large и SmallNum значений Small

```
Small = Q / N
Large = Small + 1
LargerNum = Q % N
SmallNum = N - LargerNum
```